# How does astype() affect numpy mean and sum?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Python 3.4. Calculate Mean Square Error. I cannot explain how astype() affects numpy mean and sum. What form is correct?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
InputImage = cv2.imread('Crocus.jpg')
BlurredImage = cv2.GaussianBlur(InputImage, ( 5, 5), 2.0)
GrayImage = cv2.cvtColor( BlurredImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
I0 = cv2.cvtColor( InputImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
MN = float(I0.shape[0] * I0.shape[1])
MSE = np.mean((I0 - GrayImage) ** 2, axis=None)
print(MSE)
MSE = np.mean((I0.astype("float") - GrayImage.astype("float")) ** 2)
print(MSE)
MSE2 = np.sum((I0 - GrayImage) ** 2, axis=None) / MN
print(MSE2)
MSE2 = np.sum((I0.astype("float") - GrayImage.astype("float")) ** 2) / MN
print(MSE2)
```

Output is (for my image):

```
63.4138313802
224.549664714
63.4138313802
224.549664714
```

astype("float") gives a different answer for both formula. The image values are all uint8. Why does float make a difference in the result? What is the correct answer?

Paul, thanks. The numbers are uint8, so the difference cannot be less than zero. Converting the array to int8 or float will handle the difference.

Comment: I have to admit I'm confused now. Converting to `int8` shouldn't help because modulo 256 the squares of the differences you get with either `uint8` or `int8` should be the same. Since the true squares are positive, the `int8` result cannot be more accurate than the `uint8` result, can it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure what you are seeing is overflow in the square:

```
import numpy as np

mock_data = np.random.randint(0, 256, (100,)).astype(np.uint8)
blurred = np.convolve(mock_data, (0.25,0.5,0.25), 'same').astype(np.uint8)

print(np.mean((mock_data-blurred)**2))
print(np.mean((mock_data.astype(float)-blurred.astype(float))**2))

# truncating squared floats below 256 gives same result as uint8
print(np.mean(((mock_data.astype(float)-blurred.astype(float))**2) % 256))

# squared uint8 is truncated below 256
print(np.all((mock_data-blurred)**2 < 256))

# but non-squared difference is not bounded by +/-16 
print(np.all((np.abs(mock_data-blurred)) < 16))
```

Prints:

```
115.87
2337.95
115.87
True
False
```

So, my advice is to use the float result.